# Symfony2 do Form validation rather then database validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony, encryption

i have a CreditCard entity, now i want to perform basic validation on this, in the entity, such as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\CardScheme(
 *     schemes={"VISA", "MASTERCARD", "DISCOVER", "DINERS"},
 *     message="The card number is not valid, we only support Visa, Mastercard, Discover og Diners club."
 * )
 */
private $number;
```

But the issue is that i am storing the card numbers encrypted.

They end up looking a whole lot different, and in my form type, i do this to encrypt the values and remove all the uneccesary stuff.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('number')
        ->add('expiration_year', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $this->buildYearChoices()
        ))
        ->add('expiration_month', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => array(
                '01' => '01',
                '02' => '02',
                '03' => '03',
                '04' => '04',
                '05' => '05',
                '06' => '06',
                '07' => '07',
                '08' => '08',
                '09' => '09',
                '10' => '10',
                '11' => '11',
                '12' => '12',
            )
        ))
        ->add('cvc', 'text');

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $data['number']);

        $data['number'] = $number;

        $event->setData($data);
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $credit_card = $event->getData();
        $number = $credit_card->getNumber();

        $customer_helper = $this->container->get('customer_helper');

        $crypt = $customer_helper->encryptCreditCardNumber($number);
        $credit_card->setNumber($crypt);

        $event->setData($credit_card);
    });

}
```

Even tho i know the form validation is performed pre_submit, i stil get a validation error, when i encrypt it on SUBMIT instead

**EDIT: Encrypt and decrypt emthods:**

```
public function encryptCreditCardNumber($plaintext) {
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER, self::MODE); //Gets the size of the IV belonging to a specific cipher/mode combination.
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM); //Creates an initialization vector (IV) from a random source.
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(self::CIPHER, $this->container->getParameter('cc_encryption_key'), $plaintext, self::MODE, $iv); //Encrypts the data and returns it.
    return base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext); //Encode Base 64
}

public function decryptCreditCardNumber($ciphertext) {
    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext); //Decode Base 64
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER, self::MODE); //Gets the size of the IV belonging to a specific cipher/mode combination.
    if (strlen($ciphertext) < $ivSize) {
        throw new Exception('Missing initialization vector');
    }

    $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $ivSize);
    $ciphertext = substr($ciphertext, $ivSize);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(self::CIPHER, $this->container->getParameter('cc_encryption_key'), $ciphertext, self::MODE, $iv); //Decrypts the data and returns it.
    return rtrim($plaintext, "\0");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the doctrine events `prePersist` and `preUpdate` to replace the plain code with the encrypted one on the fly (right before persisting the data, well after form validation).

To decrypt it, you can use `postLoad`.

More about [doctrine events is here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html).

Note that the doctrine events are different from the form events and do not interfere with the form or validation (there might even not be a form at all).

**EDIT:** Inject key

Whenever you need to inject static information into an entity, such as a parameter or a function, use dependency injection.

If you have a bundle, go to the `DependencyInjection` folder and edit the `Configuration.php` file (or was it the other one? I don't remember now).

What you want to find is the method that loads the parameters with the `load` method.

Right after that, fetch the desired parameter from the configuration and set it in a **static** member of the class with something like this:

```
MyEntity::$secretKey = $configuration->getParameter('secretkey');
```

Inside the entity just peruse the information with:

```
self::$secretKey
```

I write this out of the top of my head, so many inaccuracies may have slipped in. Correct where necessary. The point is all about *injecting the parameter statically* as shown above.

Comment: The issue with this, is that i need to place the events in my entity right? And the encryption key is stored in parameters.yml, so i dont save it in code, but i can't get the container into the entity

Comment: And doing that would be bad practise as far as i understand

Comment: I posted my encrypt and decrypt methods, to clarify

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you how to inject the key.

Comment: The answer should now outline how to solve the problem and should be pretty easy to implement. Forgive late-night errors if there are some.

Comment: thanks, il try this, doing it in the entity does seem like a much better choice

Comment: Yes you'll have more cohesion. Furthermore, setting the data during dependency injection is exactly what that technique's name is all about.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a non mapped entity property for the validation purposes:

```
/**
 * @Assert\CardScheme(
 *     schemes={"VISA", "MASTERCARD", "DISCOVER", "DINERS"},
 *     message="The card number is not valid, we only support Visa, Mastercard, Discover og Diners club."
 * )
 */
private $rawNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $number;
```

And then set the number with encrypted value of the rawNumber after the form validation:

```
$creditCard->setNumber(
    your_encryption_function(
        $creditCard->getRawNumber()
    )
);
```